# How to retain viewport (scroll position) on WP Listbox?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

I know that this question has already been asked here, but no answered. So I ask again, but providing my own investigation on this to see if we can solve this problem.

**The problem**

We have a databound ListBox. I want it to retain the viewport (the elements that are being shown) when I add new elements to the data source. This way, I can add new elements without changing the view.

The current WP behaviour is retain scroll position (ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset is constant). This way, when you add new elements, all of them go down.

**Possible solutions**

I've been digging a lot with this, and I have some clues.

- Disabling the data source refresh when the list is not at the top. This way, we can add new items without changing the viewport. The problem: when the user goes to the top again, all of the new elements appear all of a sudden at the top of the list, thus way losing continuity.
- Get the current item being viewed and restore it with `ScrollIntoView` when all new elements have been adding. This may seem the best option at first, but believe me it's not. First, getting the current item being viewed is not easy: it can be done with [LinqToVisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) but it's not exact (you can only guess it, the viewport buffers' size are not constant) so we will not restore the exact position the user was previously. And this solution would "jump": there would be two scroll events from the user's point of view, and that's not good.
- Calculate the vertical size of all the elements being added to compensate the vertical offset. This seems like a good solution (I'm currently investigating it), but I fear that it will also have that "jumpy" effect. It would be done overriding the `PrepareContainerForItemOverride` method in Listbox. When the base method has already prepared the container, get its height and add it to a counter. Then, when the load has finished, scroll to the vertical offset obtained. It's impossible to do it continously (we can only call the `ScrollToVerticalOffset` method, which doesn't scroll instantly) so I don't think that this will end up being the definitive solution.

My guess is that, to accomplish this, we should go deep into the Listbox definitions. Somewhere, the Listbox manages the CollectionChanged event of the ItemsSource property. There, the list decides to recreate the buffers ([more on Listbox buffers here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/05/16/listbox-why-art-thou-blanking.aspx)). As those depend on the VerticalOffset property of the ScrollViewer (constant), the viewport changes. We should modify the Listbox so it doesn't recreate buffers. The problem is that I don't have a clue on how to do this.

Any idea on this?

Thanks!

**Edit:** It's obvious that I'm using an ObservableCollection to add the items. I'm not refreshing the ItemsSource property itself.

Answer (score -2):

You should use `ObservableCollection` as `ItemsSource` for `ListBox`. So whenever you add object to your `ObservableCollection`, `ListBox` will retain its view. The magic is that `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface

See [How to use ObservableCollection](http://www.jarredcapellman.com/2012/02/18/windows-phone-7-observablecollection-populating-a-listbox-asynchronously/)

See [How to use INotifyPropertyChanged interface](http://squarkz.com/2011/02/wp7-using-inotifypropertychanged-to-dynamically-bind-changes-to-gui-controls/)

Comment: I already use ObservableCollection (well, a modification so it's thread-safe, but it implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`). That's not the problem. When you add items to the top of that `ObservableCollection` the list keeps the vertical offset and the items are moved down.